# Include shared dynamic library in jni ndk build

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, titanium

I am trying to compile a ndk module for my android app with a Shared Library provided with these drivers:
http://www.extendo-printer.de/fileadmin/user_upload/extendo/Drivers/X-56-Hengstler-Extendo-LinuxDrivers-S684018-R2-V1_01-FINAL-2009JUL15.zip

I can compile fine with the defaults (using Hello JNI example). But when I add my code the my C file which references a .so library I need to work with I get compile errors stating it can not find the methods defined in the library. When I try to include it in Android.mk in LOCAL_SRC_FILES i get warnings when it builds (unsupported file extension) but it builds, but than my native method call fails (java.lang linkage error). Is there a proper way to include a .so and than reference it's functions in your native C code?

current Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := x56-jni
LOCAL_LDLIBS := libExoApi.so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := x56-jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I tried with LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES as well with same build error. I've also tried adding to LOCAL_SRC_FILES as stated above (LOCAL_SRC_FILES := x56-jni.c libExoApi.so) with a "," and as well as \ syntax.

**Update**
I've updated Android.mk to:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libExoApi 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libExoApi.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := x56-jni
LOCAL_LDLIBS := libExoApi.so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := x56-jni.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libExoApi

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This fails at:

```
[exec]  Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/var/folders/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T//michael/usbserial-generated/libs/armeabi/libExoApi.so'
```

Comment: Show us your Android.mk file